# How to change from XDocument to XMLDocument Code?

Tags: c#, winforms, xmldocument

Hey I have two xml files and the following Code:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        List<string> headingNames = new List<string>();
        List<string> valueNames = new List<string>();

        //first xml file
        XDocument config = XDocument.Load(configFile);

        Dictionary<string, string> dict = config.Descendants("Columns").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
            .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("XPath"), y => (string)y.Attribute("Name"))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        //second xml file
        XDocument data = XDocument.Load(dataFile);

        List<XElement> positions = data.Descendants("Position").ToList();
```

But I have to change it into XMLDocument code.

Here the first XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
 <Columns BaseXPath="//Orders/Position/">
  <Colum XPath="@PositionSK" Name="Position"/>
  <Colum XPath="@PosGroup" Name="Gruppen-Nr"/>
  <Colum XPath="@PosNumber" Name="PositionsNr"/>
  <Colum XPath="@PositionCommercialTypeSK" Name="Status"/>
  <Colum XPath="@BundlePositionSK" Name="BundlePositionSK"/>
  <Colum XPath="@MainPositionSK" Name="MainPositionSK"/>
  <Colum XPath="@SalesAgentPrice" Name="Preis"/>
  <Colum XPath="@Catchword" Name="Suchwort"/> 
  <Colum XPath="@ContentComponentCommSK" Name="IKO"/>
  <Colum XPath="@PositionTypeSK" Name="PositionsTyp"/>
  <Colum XPath="//Advertisement[@AdvertisementSK = PositionAdvertisementRelationship/@AdvertisementSK]/@AdvertisementSK" Name="AdvertisementSK"/>
  <Colum XPath="//Advertisement[@AdvertisementSK = PositionAdvertisementRelationship/@AdvertisementSK]/@AdvertisementTypeSK" Name="Formatvorgabe"/>
 </Columns>
</ROOT>
```

I want to have all the names with the @ and the "Name": Position, Gruppen-Nr, ...

So in the Dic (from my code) is standing **{[@PositionSK, Position]}, {[@PosGroup, Gruppen-Nr]}, ...**

So how can I reach the same result with the XMLDocument?

In the next step I have:

```
        foreach (XElement position in positions.Where(e => e.HasAttributes))
        {
            valueNames.Clear();
            headingNames.Clear();

            foreach (XAttribute attribute in position.Attributes().Where(a => dict.ContainsKey($"@{a.Name.LocalName}")))
            {
                string name = attribute.Name.LocalName;
                string xName = dict["@" + name];
                string value = (string)attribute;

                headingNames.Add(xName);

                valueNames.Add(value);
            }
```

The output will be a DataTable at a DataGridView.
It should search the Names with the @ in another xml file and find their value. But need the code with XMLDocument.. and not with linq.. can anybody help me?

Comment: Whats wrong with your code? Why does your approach not work?

Comment: Its just a little code snippet from a bigger code.. and later it is more easier with XMLDocument, thats why I want to change these code to XMLDocument, just need a little bit help, how to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic example of this would be:

```
List<string> valueNames = new List<string>();
List<string> headingNames = new List<string>();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("data.xml");

for (int r = 0; r < doc.ChildNodes.Count; r++)
{
    var currentNode = doc.ChildNodes.Item(r);
    if (currentNode.Name.Equals("ROOT"))
    {
        var columnsNode = currentNode.FirstChild;

        for (int i = 0; i < columnsNode.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlNode child = columnsNode.ChildNodes.Item(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < child.Attributes.Count; j++)
            {
                var attribute = child.Attributes.Item(j);
                if (attribute.Name.Equals("XPath"))
                {
                    headingNames.Add(attribute.Value);
                }
                else if (attribute.Name.Equals("Name"))
                {
                    valueNames.Add(attribute.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some explanation:

- <del>Your example XML has no XML Declaration, so we can get the Root Element simply be accessing the `FirstChild` property.</del>
- After Edit: Your example XML has now a XML Declaration, but the pattern is the same. For-Loop and accessing Child Elements per Indexer of this loop.
- The 'Columns' Element can be reached the same way.
- On the 'Columns' Element we for-loop through all Child Nodes and using the indexer (i) of our loop to get the corresponding element. Why? Because it's an `XmlNodeList` Object.
- With our `XmlNode child` we do the same, but this time not with Child Nodes. Instead we loop through the Attribute Nodes and looking for the correct name.

Comment: Ah thank you! But I've edited my XML, because there is the first line missing.. So it won't work with "FirstChild"..

Comment: @Lizzy I hope you see the pattern of accessing `XmlDocument` Elements. For-Looping and using the `.Item(int index)` method.

Comment: Yeah that works :) Only thing is, I have to search after the value in the second xml file. So I have all the names, but not their right value. In my code the list `positions` is from the second xml file. In there are all the values. I will edit the code to show you what I mean.

Comment: @Lizzy That would be a breaking of StackOverflow rules. One Question, one Answer, no Editing. Please mark the Answer for further readers.

Comment: Hm, but in my question, there is also the part with the "value", so its not a second question. :D But thank you I will send you my code then. :)